# variable scope in c++ function called through R with sourceCpp

Tags: r, scope, rcpp

I have one function nested inside another in R. Since the deeper one is a bit slow, I decided to use sourceCpp to swap in some compiled code. However, that inner function uses variables defined in the outer function. In R I use environments. What's the c++ analog? Do I have to use the extern keyword? Would something like this work?

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat myFunc(arma::mat a, arma::mat b){
  extern arma::mat c;
  return a + b + c;
}
```

Comment: This is already a bad idea to do this in R code, so don't do it in C++ code. You could as Dirk said pass an environment or find a clever way to unroll the frames from your c++ functions, but I'm not showing it.

Comment: Just explicitly pass in the variables you need to the function: R copies them when _modified_, not when the function is called

Comment: Should I still if I'm using optim(initial.par, Linn(), ...)? Linn() typically relies on variables that aren't in the local scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass R environments down to C++ just fine via Rcpp; and examples exists in the docs, here, and in other places.  Just randomly tossing a C++ `extern` in there, however, does access an environment.

Comment: So select elements from an outer environment like in here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671862/read-variables-from-global-environment-with-inline-rcpp